# Angular 2 directive override component's input

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a Paragraph component and it has an input called "align". I want to be able to override this input in a directive.

```
@Component({
  selector: "paragraph",
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: `
       <p [style.text-align]="align">
          <ng-content></ng-content>
       </p>`
})
export class Paragraph {

  @Input("align")
  align: String= "justify";

}
```

Proposed directive is below;

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'paragraph',

})
export class ParagraphModifyDirective {

  @Input()
  align: string = "center";

}
```

How can I do this in Angular 2 ?
Thanks

Comment: Why in a directive? It's already an input to the component.

Comment: I need to manipulate an input inside a directive.

Comment: manipulate at which event?

Comment: Could you give a more illustrative example? How and why would you like to use this?

Comment: I want to give a choice to users to change align.

Comment: What it the problem with changing `@Input` from parent component?

Comment: I have some more component like Paragraph and I want to modify inputs in single directive.

Comment: Another way can I change a input of a component with belonging ElementRef?